# IMO $2014$ shortlist question. PigeonHole-Principle to solve?

Tags: contest-math, pigeonhole-principle

> A coin is called a *Cape Town coin* if its value is $1/n$ for some positive integer n. Given
>   a collection of Cape Town coins of total value at most $99+{1\over 2}$
>   , prove that it is ***possible*** to split
>   this collection into at most 100 groups each of total value at most $1$.

I tried it using Pigeon Hole Principle but I'm stuck when making pigeons and holes.
Can anyone help me with this? Or prove that it can't be done in that way.

[A solution to this question.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2014_IMO_Problems/Problem_5)

PS: Please don't miss the emphasized word possible.

Comment: Trying to understand this: Why can't $n = 200$ and each CT coin has value $1/200$. Each group has just one coin. So $100$ groups will have value $0.5$. I can split into more than $100$ groups. What am I missing?

Comment: @sku-check whether this helps https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2014_IMO_Problems/Problem_5

Comment: I am trying to understand the constraints of the problem. In my example, I can have lot more than $100$ groups. so what gives?

Comment: This question is false.  let $n = 3000$ and suppose you 400 coins.  You divide them into 200 groups of 2.  Then: your total is value if $\frac {400}{3000} < 99\frac 12$, each group is worth $\frac 2{3000} < 1$ and you have more than 100 groups.

Comment: @fleablood first consider that this question isn't a shortlist problem really but it came in 2014. Also I think you and I are missing something. Also I have posted a solution do check it.

Comment: Not *at most 100*.  That you *always* split it into 100 or fewer.  Not that more than 100 is impossible.

Comment: If you posted an answer then why are you posting the question?

Comment: @fleablood both means same as possible word is written

Comment: @fleablood because I dont need answer to that problem but to my problem which is can it be solved using PHP

Comment: No. When talking about possiblities they have different meaning.  "at most 100 is possible" means that it is impossible to do it with more than 100.  That is obviously false.  "is possible with 100 or less" means "you might be able to do it with 100 or more but you can definitely always do it with 100 or less".

Comment: Possible word is written and it tells something. It isn't trivially written. I have an official pdf paper which has question in the same form as I have posted.

Comment: Huh?  If you have a solution https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2014_IMO_Problems/Problem_5 the WHY are you asking the question?  If you don't *understand* the solution *ask* about the part you don't understand.  Don't ask us to do the whole thing when you have a solution!

Comment: " I have an official pdf paper which has question in the same form as I have posted. "  Then the person who wrote it used incorrect language.  That's understandable if the person isn't an english speaker.  But "it is possible to split into at most 100" would be interpretted by any english speaker as "it is impossible to split into more than 100". (Although it is actually ambiguous.)

Comment: There seems to be an official solution on page 72 in this pdf. https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2014SL.pdf

Comment: PHP is usually phrased the other way, to show that at least some number of categories is required.  I'm doubtful it is possible to apply it without major surgery on the problem statement.